# How to show original password of admin

Tags: php

I want to show original/decrypt password of admin. i am using blowfish
**$password=password_hash($adminpass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);** please tell me how to decrypt this password field

[this is the output of admin record.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQG3a.png)

Comment: Please see: [Uploading images of tables considered harmful?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403699/12672179)

Comment: Once the password is hashed there is no way to reverse the hashing.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: dont hash that password if you wanna to see user password, the reason why developer hashing password is too commit that "Even myself didnt know costumer/user password". So, if you or ur costumer forgot their password, u need to make a 'reset password/forgot password' page. And verify by email.